# Consecutive addition of numbers in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a new programmer learning python and am having trouble with how to approach this task:

So essentially I have a string of numbers to read imported from a file, and need to add the sum of the first number to the second and convert it to the correct ascii character.  So, for example if I am reading the string:

```
'36 30 25 40 80 4'
```

I would want to add 36 to 30, then 25 to 40, then 80 to 4 and so on, before converting them to the corresponding ASCII character and printing (so in this case 'CAT').

So far i recognize that i need to use a split command to split the string, and then a for loop to take the data for consecutive numbers. I can get the correct value for the first letter, but am having trouble 'telling' the program to atuomatically move on to add [2] to [3] after adding [1] to [0]. I also need to do this for multiple lines.

Again, I'm a new coder so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting cats and bats mixed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method that is less opaque (though more verbose) than Patrick's proposal would be:

```
>>> x = '36 30 25 40 80 4'
>>> nums = [int(n) for n in x.split()]
>>> ''.join(chr(sum(nums[i:i+2])) for i in range(0, len(nums), 2))
'BAT'
```

Comment: This was actually much easier to understand than Patrick's as I haven't learned map and zip functions yet. Thanks!

Comment: @chillbro at jsbuenos suggestion, I've edited in a brief overview of what's going on in my example, so I hope that helps you understand what I'm doing there. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a special usage of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up elements:

```
s = '36 30 25 40 80 4'
ints = map(int, s.split()) #make into list of ints
sums = map(sum, zip(*[iter(ints)]*2))
print(''.join([chr(i) for i in sums]))
```

Edit: technically the `iter` is unnecessary here, but I write it because I sometimes forget when I do need it.

Edit 2: addressing jsbuenos points below:

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map) takes a function and an iterable (like a list) and applies the function to every element of that iterable. So `list(map(int, ['1', '2']))` is the same as `[int('1'), int('2')]`.  The `list` is there because `map` actually returns an iterator that produces the values one at a time instead of all at once.

The usage of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) here looks complex, but that's mostly all the punctuation.  Let's try and break it down.  As I mentioned, we don't need the `iter` here because `ints` is a `map` object, and thus already an iterator, so we don't have to make an iterator for it.  So now it looks like

```
sums = map(sum, zip(*[ints]*2))
```

All the `map` is doing is adding up the pairs after we pair them up, so let's discard that too.

```
zip(*[ints]*2)
```

The trick to understanding this is understanding that list multiplication happens first

```
zip(*[ints, ints])
```

The `*` in front of an iterable is the unpacking operator.  Think of it as the list dumping its arguments into the function

```
zip(ints, ints)
```

So what is `zip` actually doing?  The normal usage of `zip` is to take two iterables and pair the elements up, like so.

```
list(zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])) #put the results from zip into a list
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

It works with more than two lists too, but that's not what we're here for.

It's important to note that in `zip(ints, ints)` the two `ints` arguments are the same object.  This means that when zip makes the first pair, it first gets the next element from its first argument, `ints`.  That's `36`.  Then it gets the next element from its second argument which is the same `ints`.  So the next element is `30`.  It then yields those two elements in a tuple, and goes on to repeat the process for the rest of the iterator.

If you're asking yourself "Why write `zip(*[iter(ints)]*2)` when `zip(ints, ints)` means the same thing?" it's because you have to make sure that the arguments are the same object, or it doesn't work.  Doing `zip(iter(ints),iter(ints))` wouldn't work because each `iter` returns a different, though identical, iterator. I have trouble remembering when I have to use `iter`, so to play it safe I just use it all the time.

Comment: "Technically" I have serious doubts whether you are actually helping any self-proclaimed "new coder" with syntax like that without explaining yourself.

Comment: @jsbueno Sorry, i don't quite follow.  Are you saying that i should remove the disclaimer, that i should remove the `iter`, or that I should explain what `iter` is doing here?

Comment: I am saying that you should add another example, with a simple, mlultiline `for` on top of that, write in plain English wht is going on, and them keep your current  example, and explain int in plain English - otherwise this answer is just good as code golfing for yourself, not for the OP - who won't understand none of  `map`, `zip` and the comprehension at the end.

Comment: `map(sum, zip(*[iter(s)]*2))` is not very pythonic

Comment: @PatrickHaugh The explanation is enlightening, but this approach still strikes me more as a "cool hack" than a best practice.

Comment: @brianpck in retrospect it's probably overkill for this problem, but for a more generalized use case of clustering data from an iterator into n-length groups i can't think of  a simpler way, especially for those iterators that don't support indexing or slicing

Comment: As a new coder, I appreciate the effort to explain it all thanks

Answer (score 2):

If this is ascii encoding, I think you actually have 'BAT' instead of 'CAT'.

```
>>> s = '36 30 25 40 80 4'
>>> ints = [int(n) for n in s.split()]             # convert strings to integers
>>> summed = [x+y for x,y in zip(ints[0::2], ints[1::2])]        # summing pairs
>>> bytearray(summed).decode('ascii')                   # decoding to ascii text
'BAT'
```

Comment: `bytearray(summed).decode('ascii') ` something out of the box, +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a no brainer like this:

```
In [18]: str='36 30 25 40 80 4'

In [19]: nums=str.split()

In [20]: for i in range(0, len(nums), 2):
    print(int(nums[i]) + int(nums[i+1]))
   ....:     
66
65
84
```

Possibly you want to check, that the len(nums) is even. If not an IndexError will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it using *list comprehesnion* as:

```
>>> my_string = '36 30 25 40 80 4'
>>> num_list = [int(num) for num in my_string.split()] # list of numbers
>>> ''.join(chr(sum(c_num)) for c_num in zip(num_list[:-1:2], num_list[1::2]))
'BAT'     #                                    ^ iterate simultaneous value with step 2
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop with range with step 2

```
    for i in range(0, 6, 2):
        do something to el[i] and el[i+1]
```

This way you can tell program to go to wanted index. Here i in loop will get values: [0, 2, 4]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
string = '36 30 25 40 80 4'
numbers = [int(e) for e in string.split()]
res = ''.join([chr(numbers[i]+numbers[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(numbers),2)])
print(res)
```

***Output:*** BAT

Answer (score 0):

A slight alteration from Patricks answer.

```
>>> t = "36 30 25 40 80 4"
>>> t_s = map(int,t.split())
>>> t_s
[36, 30, 25, 40, 80, 4]
>>> "".join([chr(sum(c)) for c in zip(t_s[1::2],t_s[::2])])
'BAT'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use extended list slicing to get pairs of adjacent numbers:

```
s = '36 30 25 40 80 4'
a = [int(x) for x in s.split()] #convert to integers
firsthalf = a[::2] #every other starting from 0
secondhalf = a[1::2] #every other starting from 1
```

Then you can use `zip` to pair the halves to be summed:

```
pairs = zip(firsthalf, secondhalf)
```

then you can map `sum` on each part of paris:

```
ordinals = [sum(x) for x in pairs]
```

to finally convert to a string, call:

```
print(''.join([chr(x) for x in ordinals])) #prints: 'BAT'
```

Answer (score 0):

Many way to do this but without creating a number of intermediate lists you can simply create an iterator and use a generator to construct the string:

```
>>> s = '36 30 25 40 80 4'
>>> i = iter(map(int, s.split()))
>>> ''.join(chr(sum(x)) for x in zip(i, i))
'BAT'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to the iterator returning ints, and use `next` function inside a list comprehension:

```
s = '36 30 25 40 80 4' 

# iter is not necessary in python3
itr = iter(map(int, s.split()))
word = ''.join(chr(a+next(itr)) for a in itr)

print(word)
# BAT
```

IMO this is a bit cleaner because there is no explicit indexing.